# Python - How to detect whether coming connections using proxy or not

Tags: python, proxy, packet-sniffers

I am working on a simple program written in **Python** which sniffs coming network packets. Then, let user use added modules like DoS detection or Ping prevention. With the help of sniffer, I can get incoming connections' *IP address*, *MAC address*, *protocol flag* and *packet content*. Now, what I want to do is adding a new module that **detects whether sender using *proxy*** or not and do some thing according to it. I was searched on the methods that can be used with Python but can not find useful one. How many ways are there to detect proxy for Python?

My sniffer code part is something like that:

```
.....
sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 8)
while True:
    packet = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    ipheader = packet[0][14:34]
    ip_hdr = struct.unpack("!8sB3s4s4s", ipheader)
    sourceIP = socket.inet_ntoa(ip_hdr[3])
    tcpheader = packet[0][34:54]
    tcp_hdr = struct.unpack("!HH9ss6s", tcpheader)
    protoFlag = binascii.hexlify(tcp_hdr[3])
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you mean ***incoming*** packets.
secondly,

> From the server TCP's point of view it is connected to the proxy, not the downstream client.

so your server can't identify that there is a proxy involved from the packet.
however, if you are in the application level like http proxy, there might be a `X-forwarded-for` header available in which there will be the original client IP. I said it might be because proxy server will decide whether or not send this header to you. If you are expecting incoming http connections to your server, you can take a look at python's  [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2) although I'm not sure if you can access the `X-forwarded-for` using this library.

From the docs:

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
>
> ...
>
> This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods:
>
> geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed
>
> info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an mimetools.Message instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP Headers)

so using info() will retrieve the headers. hope you find what you're looking for in there.

Comment: Alright, then apart from that sniffer are there another ways that I can use to detect proxies with the Python?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many ways to do this, as proxies / VPNs look like real traffic. To add to what Mid said, you can look for headers and/or user agents to help you determine if the user is using a proxy or a VPN.

The only free solution I know is getIPIntel that uses block lists, machine learning, and statistics to determine if the IP is a proxy / VPN or not.

There are other paid solutions like maxmind and blocked.

What you'll need to do is send API queries to these services and parse the results.

Comment: I'm planning to create a module that checks first on the whatismyipaddress(http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/), then according to result it will check big proxy lists for that IP but my only concern here is its speed. What do you think about it? Those checkings may slow down my tool even if I use threads?

Comment: Whatsmyipaddress isn't that accurate. For example, look up the IP 104.255.227.xxx on the two different services. Furthermore, whatsmyipaddress might block your automated queries if you're making too many of them compared to GetIPIntel which is made for automated queries.

Of course, query external services will result in a slow down but it shouldn't be that long. Do some testing on your end to see if it's acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I tested it with whatismyipaddress some proxy addresses that are listed under other 'up to date' proxy databases on the web are not detected with whatismyipaddress. That is why I'm planning to check all databases I found together with whatismyipaddress and GetIPIntel. I think giving points according to those tests, and then using that point will be more successful. For example; one IP gets 0.1 from whatis..., and 0.1 for each proxy databases. Total point such as;0.7 will be point that I will be examine. The reason why I want to use many different sources is to make it more accurate.

Comment: That makes sense. Pulling data from multiple sources and saying which source outweighs the other if there's a conflict is a good choice. If you add too many, there's an issue with "speed" as you've mentioned before. Best of luck on your implementation.